# Select * from A where (x,y) in (select x,y from B)

Tags: sas

my first time here :)

I found it very difficult to believe SAS does not support the above query.
This was very useful in Oracle, and now I need something similar in SAS.

Could you please suggest a simple solution to do that?

Thanks alot,

Gal.

Comment: Why do you find it hard to believe SAS SQL does not support a nonstandard syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
proc sql;
   select a.*
   from a, b
   where a.x = b.x and a.y = b.y;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
proc sql;
    create table TABLENAME as
    select a.*, b.x, b.y
    from Table1 A left join Table2 B
    on a.x = b.x
        and a.y = b.y
;quit;
```